# How to dual boot windows 10 and windows 8 in legacy mode?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I currently have windows 10 single boot.
I recently installed windows 8.1 on one partition of my hard disk.
When I restarted, there was just a blank screen for about 10 minutes and then showed some error(dont remember now). I kept the primary OS as windows 10 during the setup.
After I tried to boot again it took the same time but this time it booted into windows 10. I immediately deleted windows 8.1 from MSConfig and deleted the partition. 
If I want to do this again, how can I?

Comment: How you dual boot Windows has not changed.  You install Windows 8 then you install Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

When you install an earlier Windows version usually its boot manager is set in control.

But (for example) Windows 8/8.1 boot manager cannot boot Windows 10.

After installation of Windows 8/8.1 you can run [Dual-boot Repair tool](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) which has "Automatic Repair" option - it puts Windows 10 again in control of system boot.